# Not enough disk space for installing Ubuntu 11.04 - how to clean up?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-11.04

I have a Dell Mini 910. There is no Windows on it, so the laptop can't boot up.

I created a bootable USB disk with Ubuntu 11.04 and I am trying to install it, but I have a problem.

The hard drive of the Dell is 8 GB and Ubuntu 11 wants at least 4.4 GB to install. So, at some point, the installation progress stops because there is no free space. How do I clean my hard disk in order to get more free space to install Ubuntu 11?

Comment: Not programming-related - try http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

When you start up Ubuntu 11 you can do a "Live Test" this will allow you to run Ubuntu 11 from the CD from here you can access the hard drive and simply format it using gparted > Restart the machine > Install Ubuntu 11
[image]

Comment: <offtopic>What program did you take that screenshot with?</offtopic>

Comment: @Steve Martin - you can see the name at the top of the Window.. "GParted". GParted is an epic utility for non-destructively resizing partitions. You can get an ISO with it on it from their website, or just use the Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: @Phoenix yes goarted is very good but i meant the actuall screen shot, to take a screenshot with rounded corners and drop shadow.

Comment: Gparted stupid iPhone

Comment: Actually did it in photoshop for another project